# JavaFX Keep view in window

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2

I have this problem that I have been trying to solve for about an hour now:
I want my app to resize in this fashion. When the window gets smaller, the views should move to stay inside the layout. So I don't need them to necessarily change size, but I do need them the move to stay within the window.

I have already tried GridPane but I want to be more precise than a grid (like AnchorPane) since I will have many views in the layout. However, if there is a workaround involving GridPane, I will be open to those solutions as well. 
Thanks for any help and please leave a comment if you need further clarification.

Comment: Post what you have please.

Comment: I have no code. I just need to know what I can do in order to get what I want.